# Each vs. Either

Tags: difference, word-difference

I wrote:

> For example, in English where phrases of a sentence have an almost fixed order, using the phrase structure is more common, while for languages with more flexible word order, the dependency structure is more suitable. This choice also depends on the power of  the available parsers **for each formalism**.

*for each formalism* or *for either formalism*? what is the difference?

I think if I use **each**, I mean they consider the power of the parsers for phrase structure and the power of the parsers for the dependency structure and then decide based on the comparison

but I don't know the effect of **either**, and what would be the meaning if I use **either**.

Comment: You should include your understanding regarding the meaning/usage of each vs. either. I see only two formalisms (fixed order and flexible order), so I don't understand what he confusion is.

Comment: @user3169 I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Each** indicates a **definite** property. There is no way around it: the choice will always depend on the power of available parsers.

**Either** indicates a **tentative** property. Perhaps the choice depends on the power of available parsers for **some** formalisms, but other formalisms can be chosen regardless of the power of available parsers.

Admittedly, for the example you gave, the difference is not that great, and **each** and **either** can be used almost interchangeably.

Perhaps some better examples:

> Each party may lose support given the recent crisis

In this case, any party in our fictional country may see angry voters.

> Either party may lose support given the recent crisis

Some parties may lose support, because they handled the situation badly. Other parties may not see an effect, perhaps because their voters don't care about the crisis at hand.

Comment: Thanks, then I think I mean **each**, because I consider the power of parsers for both formalism and decide based on their comparison

Answer (score 1):

Each: Is used to refer everyone of two or more things, or people. 
E.G 
1-Each one of us was asked a question.
2-Each room must be cleaned.

Either: One or the other of two people or things.
E.G
1- You will either do it, or keep finding an excuses.
2- Either you run the day, or the day runs you.

Answer (score 0):

‘**Either**’ can only refer to one of two options: "He can sit at either end of the table" (i.e. He can chose to sit at one end or the other - but not both together).

‘**Each**’ is an equal and joint reference to all: “There are chairs at each end of the table” - i.e. at both ends. “There are tables at each side of the room”. - i.e. at all four sides.

It is therefore incorrect to write: “There are chairs at either end of the table” or “There are tables at either side of the room”.